# Prestashop Product page error

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I need help I cant find any information about this error. even in Prestashop forum

I copied my live site and transfer it to my local server..
Configurations are now OK but when I click on any product at the front-end.

I received the below error

```
Fatal error: Class 'ObjectModel' not found in F:\xampp2\htdocs\checkedentertainment\product.php on line 32
```

When I checked the product on the backend the product is still in the products and all are their smoothly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What the error says is that the class `ObjectModel` is missing. It couldn't be loaded. Many of the core classes in PrestaShop inherits from the ObjectModel so it is cruicial that it exists.

Please check your **classes** folder and make sure all your classes are there. There should be an `ObjectModel.php` file in the classes directory, if not, make sure to put it there!